# Android: wrong screen of ViewPager after rotating

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, swipe

I have really strange problem.
In my Activity I have ViewPager because I want to show different screen.
Every screen has to show its own string.
My idea is to create one activity, one ViewPager and one fragment, in which is included logic and information about which String has to be shown.

This is my Activity:

```
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.wizard_layout);

        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        maxPages = pagerAdapter.getCount();

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);    

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
```

This is my Pager Adapter

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                return StepWelcomeFragment.newInstance(position);
            }
            return null;             
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
```

This is my only one fragment

```
public static class StepWelcomeFragment extends Fragment {
        private int sectionNumber;

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static StepWelcomeFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            StepWelcomeFragment fragment = new StepWelcomeFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.sectionNumber = sectionNumber;
            return fragment;
        }

        public StepWelcomeFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard_welcome_step_layout,
                    container, false);
            switch(sectionNumber){
            case 0:     
                showString0(); break;

            case 1:
                showString1(); break;   

            case 2:
                showString2(); break;

            case 3:
                showString3(); break;

            case 4:
                showString4(); break; 
            default: break;
            }                       
            return rootView;        
        }
    }
```

I'm using variable `sectionNumber` in order to store (inside fragment itself) information about which screen has focus.

It works fine.
But, when I rotate the device, activity is destroyed and recreated (as normal) but what I see on screen is ALWAYS sting0. 
Doesn't matter if I navigate screen swiping, in every new screen (once again, just AFTER rotating) will appear just String0. `sectionNumber` is continuously 0.
Also, even without saving state, when I rotate is shown current screen, my expectation is, after rotation should be shown screen 0 (Am I wrong?).
Seems like  Activity doesn't recreate new adapter and new fragment.
What am I doing wrong?
Why, after rotating, activity is not killed and recreated properly?
I want save no data, for me it's ok to destroy and rebuilt, but why it doesn't?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got buy my self.
It was enough adding

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        /* Save which screen in visible */
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(currentViewTag, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }
```

BUT without `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` otherwise it saves the state of View instead of recreate them from scratch.